# Visual Studio 2010 x64 on university msdn

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit, msdn

In our university MSDN(http://msdn.miet.ru) visual studio 2010 only x86 version. Can I install this on Windows 7 SP1 x64? If no, please give me link to MSDN Visual Studio 2010 x64. If posible professional version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe VS2010 has only 32-bit version and technically there should not be a reason to not be able to install this on a 64-bit Windows OS.